# Como fazer um campo de busca com form_tag no rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Olá! Boa tarde. sou estudante de sistemas de informação e estou fazendo um pequeno projeto onde eu preciso colocar um form para buscar os objetos do modelo Produto que existem no banco de dados.

o modelo produto:

```
class Produto < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :fornecedor

  def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end

end
```

Produtos controller:

```
class ProdutosController < ApplicationController
  attr_accessor :nome
  before_action :set_produto, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /produtos
  # GET /produtos.json
  def index
    @produtos = Produto.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def getbusca
    @produts = Produto.search(params[:search])
  end

  def new
    @produto = Produto.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @produto = Produto.new(produto_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @produto.save
        format.html { redirect_to @produto, notice: 'Produto was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @produto }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @produto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @produto.update(produto_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @produto, notice: 'Produto was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @produto }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @produto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @produto.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to produtos_url, notice: 'Produto was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_produto
      @produto = Produto.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def produto_params
      params.require(:produto).permit(:nome, :preco, :fornecedor_id)
    end
end
```

A view inicio.html.erb do controlle Home:

```
<%= form_tag produtos_path, :action => 'getbusca', :method => 'get' do %>
      <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
      </p>
  <% end %>
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'login#new'
  get '/home/inicio', to: 'home#index'
  get '/produtos', to: 'produtos#getbusca'

  scope '/login' do
    post '/', to: 'login#criarusuario'
    get '/acesso', to:'login#new'
    post '/acessorecebendo', to:'login#create'
    get '/sair', to:'login#destroy'
  end

  resources :login
  resources :home
  resources :produtos
  resources :fornecedors
end
```

o erro:

> Couldn't find all Produtos with 'id': (all, {:conditions=>["name LIKE
>   ?", "%arroz%"]}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)

na linha:

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      **find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])**
    else
      find(:all)
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, em seu form você está colocando `produtos_path` que se refere ao ProdutosController#index de sua aplicação.

Para que você sua action `getbusca` você precisa criar essa rota e e adicionar ela em seu formulário.

Ou uma abordagem que eu considero melhor seria colocar sua busca no Index mesmo, substituindo

```
  def index
    @produtos = Produto.all
  end
```

por

```
  def index
    @produtos = Produto.search(params[:search])
  end
```

Creio que já resolveria.

**EDIT:**

Esse erro que você apresentou é gerado porque o método `find` desde o Rails 4 foi deprecated, então você deve usar `where` no lugar, segue exemplo:

```
 def self.search(search)
    if search
      where(['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
      all
    end
 end
```

Comment: Olá ! Então, já resolvi esse problema de rota e o form está redirenciando para a o method search de Produto. mas estou tendo um erro. Atualizei a questão com ele

Comment: Tente agora @MikhaelAraujo

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado ^ ^'

Comment: Opa, não há de que. Obrigado pelo upvote :)